# How can I test if a number is a square number in Python?

Tags: python

My code is

```
if graph == square_grid and type(math.sqrt(nodes)) is not int: 
    print "Your netork can't have that number of nodes"
```

Of course this doesn't work because math.sqrt always returns a float. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

One way is

```
int(math.sqrt(x)) ** 2 == x
```

Answer (score 7):

Because math.sqrt always returns a float, you can use the built in `is_integer` method

```
def is_square(x):
    answer = math.sqrt(x)
    return answer.is_integer()
```

this will return `True` if `x` is a square and `False` if it's not

```
>>> is_square(25)
True
>>> is_square(14)
False
```

Comment: Hm. Seeing as floating point numbers are imprecise, could it happen that the sqrt() of a square number will end up not being an integer because of rounding errors during the computation? That would make @larsmans's answer better.

Comment: that is a valid point, although I just ran a for loop that would print out all valid squares up to 100,000 using this method, and it didn't miss one.

Comment: Integers are exactly represented in floating point (they have all zeros after the point). I'm not sure whether `sqrt` is guaranteed to preserve that, though.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
math.sqrt(nodes) == int(math.sqrt(nodes))
```

Comment: this won't work, because of the imprecision of floats. If the difference between `math.sqrt(nodes)` and `int(math.sqrt(nodes))` is larger than `sys.float_info.epsilon` then you're out of luck.

Comment: do you mean _smaller_ than `sys.float_info.epsilon`? otherwise I'm confused…

Comment: Larger. If the difference is larger than the epsilon, the system sees them as not equal, and the expression returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure maths (no libraries) a square number can be determined in Python as follows:

```
not n**0.5 % 1
```

As the square root of a square integer is an integer, this test uses *modulo 1 equal to zero* to test if the square root is an integer.

#### For example:

The following will print the first five square numbers:

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    if not i**0.5 % 1:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
```